# Integrated security with crystal report in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

This is my code, I dont know how to set integrated security in report.SetDatabaseLogon. There is no error however the report is not getting loaded in the webform.

```
void GetUsers()
{
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
    report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Reports/rptUsers.rpt"));
    report.SetDatabaseLogon("(localdb)", "CAPROJ2");
    report.SetParameterValue("User", "Arteezy");

    crvUsers.ReportSource = report;
    crvUsers.DataBind();
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to include that my servername is (localdb)\SQL, however I tried to use this but it shows "\" unrecognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SAP](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3643844) forums, you could try:

```
report.DataSourceConnections[0].IntegratedSecurity = true;
// and/or 
report.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection("(localdb)", "CAPROJ2", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create new report document
    var rd = new ReportDocument();

    // Construct full filename pointing to rpt
    var reportFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Reports\CR\", rptFileName);

    // Load the rpt file
    rd.Load(reportFile);


    // Create connectionInfo object to override default rpt config info
    // Provide login information
    var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

    // In the form - "SERVER_NAME\\SQLEXPRESS"
    // In this example we store serverName, db, user and PW in config table
    // If userID config is not in config table, assume we will use Microsoft integrated security
    crConnectionInfo.ServerName   = serverName;
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
    if (userID != null)
    {
        crConnectionInfo.UserID   = userID;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = password;
    }
    else
    {
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    }

    // For every table defined in rpt, override login info
    var CrTables = rd.Database.Tables;
    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        var crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }
    // If this is a web service and you want to return a PDF ...
    var s = rd.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```